# Custom formatting of matrix Rows

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Any change someone here knows how I can 'pixel-perfect' format certain rows in a Matrix (Not only value. Full row). in the example some fake data. But real life scenario is related to a 9 levels deep Chart Of accounts. And i want to add for all levels  custom formatting. From  light background color, to a more darker color size for a better user experience.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I doubt this is possible with the default visuals. Power BI is not good for 'pixel-perfect' anything.

Comment: I don't like your answer, however i appreciate your support!